# Bad Method Call Exception Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Following is my route code

```
Route::get( 'generate_pdf', 'Admin\UserController@generateproviderlist' )->name('provider.pdf') ;
```

and Controller

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;
 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

 // For Uploading image, we need to include these libraries
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

 use App\User;
 use App\Profile;
 use App\ProfileAddress;
 use App\Service;
 use App\Category;
 use App\ProviderService;
 use App\ProviderCategory;

 class UserController extends Controller
 {
      public function generateproviderlist( Request $request )
     {
         $user_list = User::join('profiles', 'profiles.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                            ->where('users.is_deleted', 0)
                            ->where( 'users.user_type', 2 )
                            ->select('users.id', 'users.is_enable', 'users.email', 'users.phone',      'profiles.company_name', 'profiles.reg_number')
                            ->get() ;

         $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
         $html = view('admin.provider.provider_pdf', ['provider_list' => $user_list])->render();
         $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
         $mpdf->Output('done_list.pdf', 'D');

        return false;
     }
 }
```

When I visit the url I get an exception

```
Method App\Http\Controllers\Admin\UserController::generateproviderlist does not exist.
```

Following is the telescope url for the exception.
https://do-net.com/telescope/requests/925fbd80-c2a8-4ed5-981d-cc0a21bb9c29

I have tried Clearing the cache and changed the function name but it isn't working. the other routes are working perfectly fine.  The route is working fine on my localhost but it is giving 500 error on the live server

Comment: try to remove all the code for generating PDF and dd something on the page and see if it accessible. Other than this double check you run composer to include the pdf library.

Answer (score 0):

I did a simple laravel setup and checked your routing, indeed it works. From this, I'm theorizing that there's a mess up in your production server compared to your production.

1. Make sure your controller in your production server has the .php extension (In some cases of renaming or manually adding a file, you may have missed out the extension)
2. If number 1 isn't the case, run the following command:

   `composer dumpautoload`
3. If that doesn't work, delete the userController from your production (backup your code) and re-add by this command:

   `php artisan make:controller userController`

(This is optional, just to ensure there's no copy paste mistakes) and then add then add whatever codes you had in usercontroller except for the generate pdf code. Once you added the previous user controller code, add the generate pdf code after the last public function code in your file, like example:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function akuFunctionSatu()
    {
        //random code here
    }

    public function akuFunctionTerakhir()
    {
        //random code here
    }

    public function generateproviderlist(Request $request)
    {
        $user_list = User::join('profiles', 'profiles.user_id', '=', 'users.id')->where('users.is_deleted', 0)
            ->where('users.user_type', 2)
            ->select('users.id', 'users.is_enable', 'users.email', 'users.phone', 'profiles.company_name', 'profiles.reg_number')
            ->get();

        $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
        $html = view('admin.provider.provider_pdf', ['provider_list' => $user_list])->render();
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
        $mpdf->Output('done_list.pdf', 'D');

        return false;
    }
}
```

4. You can also do your route like this:

`Route::group(['namespace'=>'Admin'], function() {
Route::get( 'generate_pdf', 'UserController@generateproviderlist' )->name('provider.pdf') ;
});`